# Can't play 720p mkv video file

Tags: video, matroska, video-playback

I'm having trouble playing a 720p mkv file on my computer.  It won't open in Media Player Classic (with K-lite codec pack), or in GOMPlayer, but it does open in VLC.  However, in VLC, it seems like it will skip a little bit every now and then and sometimes it screws up and starts the video over at the beginning (but when it does this the audio gets messed up).

My CPU is intel i7 - 720QM and my video card is ATi Mobility Radeon HD 5870.

> General Format                                   : Matroska Format
>   version                           : Version 2 File size
>   : 394 MiB Duration                                 : 20mn 36s Overall
>   bit rate mode                    : Variable Overall bit rate
>   : 2 673 Kbps Encoded date                             : UTC 2011-08-14
>   04:12:29 Writing application                      : mkvmerge v4.1.1
>   ('Bouncin' Back') built on Jul  3 2010 22:54:08 Writing library
>   : libebml v1.0.0 + libmatroska v1.0.0 Attachment
>   : Yes / Yes / Yes / Yes / Yes
>
> Video ID                                       : 1 Format
>   : AVC Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
>   Format profile                           : High@L4.1 Format settings,
>   CABAC                   : Yes Format settings, ReFrames
>   : 8 frames Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
>   Duration                                 : 20mn 36s Width
>   : 1 280 pixels Height                                   : 720 pixels
>   Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9 Frame rate
>   : 23.976 fps Color space                              : YUV Chroma
>   subsampling                       : 4:2:0 Bit depth
>   : 8 bits Scan type                                : Progressive
>   Writing library                          : x264 core 116 r2037+602
>   fbce75d Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=8 /
>   deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x133 / me=umh / subme=10 / psy=1 /
>   fade_compensate=0.50 / psy_rd=0.70:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=24 /
>   chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 /
>   fast_pskip=0 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / sliced_threads=0 /
>   nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 /
>   constrained_intra=0 / fgo=5 / bframes=8 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 /
>   b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=400
>   / keyint_min=12 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=60 /
>   rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=16.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 /
>   qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=40000 / vbv_bufsize=30000 / crf_max=0.0 /
>   nal_hrd=none / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:0.70 Language
>   : English Default                                  : Yes Forced
>   : No
>
> Audio ID                                       : 2 Format
>   : FLAC Format/Info                              : Free Lossless Audio
>   Codec Codec ID                                 : A_FLAC Duration
>   : 20mn 36s Bit rate mode                            : Variable
>   Channel(s)                               : 2 channels Sampling rate
>   : 48.0 KHz Bit depth                                : 16 bits Writing
>   library                          : libFLAC 1.2.1 (UTC 2007-09-17)
>   Language                                 : Japanese Default
>   : Yes Forced                                   : No
>
> Text ID                                       : 3 Format
>   : ASS Codec ID                                 : S_TEXT/ASS Codec
>   ID/Info                            : Advanced Sub Station Alpha
>   Compression mode                         : Lossless Language
>   : English Default                                  : Yes Forced
>   : No
>
> Menu 00:00:00.000                             : :Prologue / :Opening /
>   :Ending 00:00:51.051                             : :Episode
>   00:18:42.622                             : :Epilogue 00:20:20.636
>   : :Preview

How can I get files like this to play properly?

Comment: Also, seeking within the file in VLC doesn't work very well.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt video. Do you have trouble with 720p mkv files in general or just with this specific one?

Answer (score 0):

I think Dennis is right.  I have tried 720p videos from another source and they play fine.  Also, when I tried to re-encode the file my encoding program gave me errors.